# place points with only distance matrix

Tags: algorithm, plot, data-visualization

I want to visualize some points, but only a distance matrix for them is given. It is there any good method to get one possible way to place them on 2D space.

Input: a distance matrix

Ouput: coordinates of these points

Answer (score 2):

For a given matrix, if you come up with a possible placement, then any translation of the points will also satisfy the matrix, as will any rotation, and also mirroring.

For one possible placement:

Choose 3 points A B C (i.e. 3 rows from the matrix) that form a triangle with distances AB, AC and BC taken from the matrix. The points can't all lie on a line, so AB != AC + BC, AC != AB + BC and BC != AB + AC.

Place A at the origin and B at (AB, 0). Then use the Cosine rule to deduce the angle between the lines AB and AC:

angle = arccos((AB<sup>2</sup> + AC<sup>2</sup> - BC<sup>2</sup>) / (2 * AB * AC))

Now that you have the angle you can calculate the position of C:

C = (cos(angle) * AC, sin(angle) * AC);

You now have positions for A B and C. You can go through each of the other rows in the matrix corresponding to the other points, and find the distance between each point and A B and C. Then you can use this formula to work out the position of the point based on your assumed positions of A B C and the distance of the point to each:

[Finding location of a point on 2D plane, given the distances to three other know points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100448/finding-location-of-a-point-on-2d-plane-given-the-distances-to-three-other-know)

So, you only actually need 3 values from each row of the matrix. For a large matrix, most of it is totally redundant. This might be helpful to you if you are trying to minimize storage space.

Remember that any translation, rotation and mirroring is also valid.

Comment: yeah, i got the point, so picking A, B needs more lucks if I want a better visualization when plot these points, is it true, or any suggestions for picking?

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? All of them are equivalent. The only thing you need to worry about is that ABC form a triangle.

Comment: "better" means points are dispersing enough. so i should pick ABC that have biggest distance to most others?

Comment: I don't think it will make a difference because the distances between all the pairs of points will be the same as it is determined by the distance matrix. Therefore dispersion will be the same. You could pick an ABC, generate the points and then compute the centroid and subtract it from each point, if you want to center them around the origin.

Comment: Does the matrix represent geometrically consistent distances between an actual set of points? Or is it arbitrary data?

Comment: yeah, it is euclidean metric